# UnsatisfiedLinkError Building Maven Project in Hudson

Tags: maven, build, hudson

I set up a "Maven2/3 project" in Hudson 2.0.1 deployed in Glassfish 3.0.1 and when I try to build, I get this error:

```
Started by user anonymous
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/hg incoming --quiet --bundle hg.bundle --template "<changeset node='{node}' author='{author|xmlescape}' rev='{rev}' date='{date}'><msg>{desc|xmlescape}</msg><added>{file_adds|stringify|xmlescape}</added><deleted>{file_dels|stringify|xmlescape}</deleted><files>{files|stringify|xmlescape}</files><parents>{parents}</parents></changeset>\n" --rev default
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/hg log --rev . --template {node}
Found mavenVersion 3.0.2 from file jar:file:/usr/local/maven/lib/maven-core-3.0.2.jar!/META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven/maven-core/pom.properties
Parsing POMs
[workspace] $ /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java -cp /home/hudson/.hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-2.0.1.jar:/usr/local/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/local/maven /opt/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/hudson-2.0.1/WEB-INF/lib/hudson-remoting-2.0.1.jar /home/hudson/.hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-2.0.1.jar 35157
<===[HUDSON REMOTING CAPACITY]===>���channel started
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Remote call on Channel to Maven [/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java, -cp, /home/hudson/.hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-2.0.1.jar:/usr/local/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar, org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main, /usr/local/maven, /opt/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/hudson-2.0.1/WEB-INF/lib/hudson-remoting-2.0.1.jar, /home/hudson/.hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-2.0.1.jar, 35157] failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:640)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:156)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:630)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:429)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1363)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:405)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1803)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1699)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1803)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1720)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1592)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1614)
    at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:263)
    at hudson.util.ColorPalette.<clinit>(ColorPalette.java:39)
    at hudson.model.BallColor.<clinit>(BallColor.java:55)
    at hudson.model.Result.<clinit>(Result.java:52)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at $Proxy2.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor37.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1737)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:178)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:98)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Sending e-mails to: email@address.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any suggestions as to why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appeared to be a result of a 32 bit JDK installed on a 64 bit OS (Linux/CentOS).  Installing a 64 bit JDK got rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Missing file? File permission problems? Check those things first on the library it's complaining about. Check which user Hudson is running as, and try running the same command as the same user to see what happens.